# Attendance tracking in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to make an attendance sheet in Excel. If a child is present, the teacher will write `P` in a cell, or `A` for absent. I have to add `l` (which indicates  a latecomer) in addition to attendance. So an entry with both `P` and `l` must also be counted in total days present; I want to get the number of `P` and `l` in a range to calculate total number of days in the month each child was present.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can count `P` with `COUNTIF`:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, "P")
```

This will give the number of times `P` appear in column A.

So, if you want to add in those that contain `I` as well, just add another `COUNTIF`:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, "P") + COUNTIF(A:A, "I")
```

Change the range as required.

Comment: Can i give default value of answers to the formula to be blank.Now it is 0 for the cells where we didnt enter data.

Comment: You can add in the cells that are blank as well. `=COUNTIF(A:A, "P") + COUNTIF(A:A, "I") + COUNTIF(A:A, "")`

Comment: if i not supply  data for an equation(because i gave equation for 50 children but a perticular class have only 45 childern so 5 raws are with out data for equation), the cell with equation in that raw comes 0.I want to change it to nil or leave it blank(No default answer.).Please help me.

Comment: @teacher Well, you would use `COUNTIFS` for this, but on another hand, the formula will be three times longer. You might merge them with `SUMPRODUCT`. If say, the names are in column A, the attendance in column B, then you could use: `=SUMPRODUCT((A:A<>"")*(B:B={"P","I",""}))`

Comment: but i already have a formula in column of total attendance.in that column only 0 comes.i want to make that colum appear blank.

Comment: @teacher I don't understand your requirement. Is it possible for you to have a picture and indicate on this, where you want the count and what should be the count there?